# Good date-picker for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I have always been a very big fan of the DHTML calendar http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/

I was planning on using this for an upcoming project in ASP.NET, but I wouldn't mind finding a new calendar control that is specifically made as a ASP.NET user control.

Does anyone know of some good ones out there that I should check out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JQuery UI has a nice calendar/datepicker worth taking a look at. And most of all its FREE! [click here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions.  I really like the simpliciy of the JQuery one, so I'll most likely end up using it.

Comment: The component are nice but I've found on several occasions that I like using jQuery because it's cleaner and you have better control. Especially for something simple like a date picker.

Comment: http://ui.jquery.com/demos/datepicker

Answer (score 3):

This one is free and I used it before I had a Telerik or DevExpress subscription.

http://www.basicdatepicker.com/bdplite

Also if you use jQuery there a few very well done date pickers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Calendar from AJAX.NET](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) with some custom tweaks (for example to correctly handle time) and [Telerik's RadCalendar](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet/prometheus/Calendar/Examples/Overview/DefaultCS.aspx) control, which is really nice (but not free).

Comment: the ajax.net calendar supports time?

Comment: It does in a way that you can select the date on the screen and after it enter the date manually. However there is a small problem to set the time because by default it handles only date. If you are interested, I can put the code to the net.

Answer (score 0):

i have (besides the great JQuery UI) two other options:

- Ajax Control Toolkit (from codeplex.com): great, free, but no support for IE6 iFrame overlay bug
- oBout Calendar (http://www.obout.com/calendar/calendar_home.aspx): 
  not free, but handles the IE6 Bug, and also has a nice "Airplane" mode, where two Calenders work together (Start/End Date)

regards
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

For really comprehensive set of date related components check out Peters Blums stuff at http://www.peterblum.com/DES/DateAndTime.aspx we have used these for years

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but the Telerik DateTimePicker went over well with my team.

Comment: renders a 110kb javascript file though

Answer (score 0):

[Ra-Ajax Calendar](http://ra-ajax.org/samples/Ajax-Calendar.aspx) is LGPL and Free of Charge to use...

Answer (score 0):

We have used the [Yahoo! UI Library Calendar](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/) with no complaints.